# Plotting norm value graph in angular with chartJS

Tags: node.js, angular, graph, charts, chart.js

I need a support in creating a graph in my Angular 16 application with chartJS v4.4.0

Following is the sample image of the graph:

[image: Graoh image]

X-axis defines percentages in 10ths (0-10, 11-20, 21-30, ...)

The area to be colored will be be given as follows:

> {   range_max : 60,   range_min : 50   }

The corresponding y axis value will be fixed to 5.

Can anyone help me to do this?